# desktop.ini for root of the drive

Tags: windows, shell-extensions, desktop.ini

In Windows, you can [bind a Shell Namespace Extension to a folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#file) by setting a System or Readonly attribute and placing a `desktop.ini` with appropriate `CLSID` inside.

However, I can't see a way to set a `system` attribute to the *root of the drive*.

Does this mean that I can't do it, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can try `attrib` from the command line, though I doubt you can link a shell namespace to the root folder; when would that ever be desirable?

Comment: a) there's seemingly no combination of attrib parameters that would affect the root of the drive; b) to display custom properties, toolbars etc. for the files that are on the drive; c) to prevent generation of thumbnails, overlay icons and so on - it's a remote drive and it slows it down a lot