# How to register a Property Handler on folders?

Tags: com, registry, windows-shell

I built a virtual filesystem (not a namespace extension) for Windows which acts as a frontend of our document management server consisting of files and folders. In order to be able to display some metadata of the DMS objects in Windows Explorer as additional selectable columns, I successfully provided properties to the Windows Property System by implementing a COM Property Handler. Wheras normal property handlers focus on specific file types for which they feel responsible, my Property Handler adds properties to all files regardless of their type. Because Property Handlers can only be registered on the file type level, I registered my handler for about 30 types under

> `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertyHandlers\<.Extension>`

However, I did not manage to register the Property Handler for folder objects. Since all objects in our file system are virtual I build the property store (`IPropertyStore`) by implementing `IInitializeWithFile` instead of `IInitializeWithStream`. The properties are requested from our DMS with the path of `IInitializeWithFile` acting as key and were not read from an objects content. This concept would work for folders as well.

For getting called on folders I tried to associate the handler by registering under different well known identifiers like `Folder`, `Directory`, `AllFileSystemObjects` and `*` instead of the file extension without success.
I also didn’t find anything in the MSDN documentation regarding this aspect.

Is there a way to register a Windows Property Handler on folders? Or is there some other way to add custom columns to folders in Windows Explorer?

Comment: If this is not a NSE, how are you implementing this virtual filesystem? A custom kernel driver and mounting it as a drive letter?

Comment: @Anders: Yes, I’m using a 3rd party kernel driver which allows to implement the filesystem in user space in .NET and mount it as a drive letter. The COM property handler is implemented in C++.

Comment: Not a real solution but the older column handler shell extension interfaces from 2000/XP still work in some of the 3rd-party Explorer replacements.

Comment: @Anders: Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately, the older column handler shell extensions do not match our general technical approach.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is possible to do this.

Property handlers are clearly not the right approach, they are system wide and there can only be one per file extension. They should only be implemented by the software that "owns" the file extension and can parse the file to extract properties.

The old column handlers would have been your best bet (IMHO) but they are officially dead and you already said you can't use them.

Have you considered creating a namespace extension? Either as a root item somewhere (Desktop or My Computer) the way My Documents used to work in 2000/XP or maybe something more along the lines of how OneDrive works?

I'm not sure if desktop.ini files work [in the root of a drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329846/desktop-ini-for-root-of-the-drive) but it might be worth looking into. You would then find yourself in the [poorly documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096(v=vs.85).aspx) land of `[.ShellClassInfo]` and its CLSID, CLSID2 and UICLSID members. The general idea would be to act as a IShellFolder proxy on top of the "real" IShellFolder so you could create a [multiplex property store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776490(v=vs.85).aspx). I think there are some (undocumented?) property keys you can override to change the folders default columns and tooltips as well.

There is also something called a [delegated folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762068(v=vs.85).aspx) that allows you to play with nested PIDLs but the documentation is once again pretty useless so I'm not sure if this is something worth looking into.

A 3rd option is to pretend to be a [cloud storage provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn889934(v=vs.85).aspx). I don't know if this gets you any closer to your goal and you would still have to implement some NSE bits to get to the point where you can layer yourself on top of the underlying IShellFolder. This feature is rather new and only documented to work on Windows 10.

The inner workings of how Explorer/IShellBrowser is connected to the IShellFolder/IShellView is one of the least documented parts of Windows. There are hundreds of undocumented interfaces. Explorer [gives DefView special treatment](http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell.narkive.com/eeyV7YsU/iexplorerpanevisibility-problems-in-vista#post10) leaving other 3rd-party implementations out in the cold.

My feeling is that there is no clean solution to implement this on top of a drive letter but you might get lucky, if Raymond Chen drops by he might have some tips for you...

Comment: Very interesting, I’ll have a deeper look into the cloud storage provider integration. However, I’ll try to give some background of our approach in which we’re bound to a real (virtual) file system because of it’s transparency. It offers transparent access to files and directories for all applications and tools which can deal with normal file system APIs by path which is important for some automation tasks or when working on the file system from the commandline. On the other hand, a NSE exposes its objects only through the shell to shell aware processes like Windows Explorer.

Comment: So, yes, we need to view the file system in Windows Explorer but not only there. Additionaly, much logic would be spread across possibly many Windows Explorer processes instead of beeing centralized in only one file system. Now, after implementing handlers for context menus, icon overlays, previews and copy hooks based on our file system approach only the small building block regarding properties on folders is missing. Thanks for you detailed answer.

Comment: A 4th thing you could try is to specify psvOuter when calling SHCreateShellFolderView in a NSE. I have never tried doing that but perhaps it gives you enough control while still letting you just use the native shell provided IShellFolder that sits on top of your filesystem. Or the brutal approach; hooking the native IShellFolders vtable members. The goal of course is not having to re-implement all the menu and icon handlers.

Comment: The brutal approach sounds most difficult but also most promising to me. For the moment we skip this task but we'll may give it a try later. Thanks.