# How to detect OneDrive online-only files

Tags: winapi, onedrive

Starting from Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (version 16299.15) and OneDrive build 17.3.7064.1005 the On-Demand Files are available for users (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-onedrive-files-on-demand-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e)

Any OneDrive file now can have one of the following type: online-only, locally available, and always available.

Using WinAPI how can I know that the file (e.g. "C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Getting started with OneDrive.pdf") is online-only file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After years, I'm still using `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS` attribute described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to determine if a file or a directory is completely present locally or not.

Microsoft docs says the following for `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS`:

> *When this attribute is set, it means that the file or directory is not fully present locally. For a file that means that not all of its data is on local storage (e.g. it may be sparse with some data still in remote storage). For a directory it means that some of the directory contents are being virtualized from another location. Reading the file / enumerating the directory will be more expensive than normal, e.g. it will cause at least some of the file/directory content to be fetched from a remote store. Only kernel-mode callers can set this bit.*

There are some advantages of `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS`:

1. It can be used for both files and directories.
2. It can be set in kernel mode only, so there is no chance for anyone to set the attribute arbitrary.

And as it described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1214542/what-do-new-windows-8-10-attributes-mean-no-scrub-file-x-integrity-v-pinn/1287315), there are still some interesting undocumented attributes which can provide additional information about cloud files.

Note: I didn't accept Jonathan Potter's answer because I mentioned FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS attribute in comments and started using it a year earlier than he updated his answer.

Comment: Cool thanks! I just put it in code: https://rokdd.xyz/tech/on-demand-files-in-python-reading-file-attributes-in-windows/

Answer (score 4):

To check for "online only" all you need is to call `GetFileAttributes()` and see if the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE` attribute is set.

In fact this isn't new for OneDrive, that attribute has existed for a long time.

There are other OneDrive attributes available via the shell (although the property you need is `PKEY_StorageProviderState` rather than `PKEY_FilePlaceholderStatus`) but "online only" is easy to check for.

Edit: Another filesystem attribute, `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_PINNED` *is* new for Windows 10, and is used by OneDrive to indicate a file that's "always available".

Edit: As of 2019 it appears that OneDrive now uses `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS` rather than `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE`, as suggested below.

Edit: PKEY_StorageProviderState was broken in Windows 10 1903, and still not fixed in 1909. It returns 4 ("uploading") for all files in any apps other than Explorer.

Comment: Are you sure FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE is applicable for OneDrive files?

Comment: @Rom098 Yes. CD to your OneDrive folder in a DOS prompt and run the `attrib` command if you don't believe me :)

Comment: some people believe that GetFileAttributes call on offline OneDrive files may cause downloading of the file. Is it true, what do you think?

Comment: It doesn't. But you can easily test this for yourself.

Comment: There are few more attributes, e.g.  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS (https://superuser.com/questions/1214542/what-do-new-windows-8-10-attributes-mean-no-scrub-file-x-integrity-v-pinn/1287315) It looks like  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE can be set by anyone, unlike FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS which can be set only in kernel mode. So FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS seems more preferrable.

Comment: Many apps are getting very confused by OneDrive on demand. Also looking for white papers on what on needs to do make one's app OneDrive on-demand friendly. Even PowerShell isn't compatible - use Copy-Item on a file that's just a placeholder (not downloaded) and it copies the right number of bytes but the target file is full of zeros, i.e. Copy-Item isn't triggering the file to be downloaded first. Not good!

Comment: Hmm maybe Windows 10/PowerShell has been updated. Copy-Item now appears to work with placeholders. You also get an "Cloud provider not running" error if OneDrive isn't running

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `PKEY_FilePlaceholderStatus` property for the file ([at the shell level](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benkaras/2006/08/29/property-consumerism/), not the file-system level). [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matthew_van_eerde/2013/09/24/shellproperty-exe-v2-read-all-properties-on-a-file-set-properties-of-certain-non-vt_lpwstr-types/) has a example program you can test. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47803994/how-to-create-an-iconlist-property-in-the-windows-property-system) also hints to some undocumented properties you might want to take a look at.

Microsoft has a UWP [example on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-determining-availability-of-microsoft-onedrive-files).

Comment: Do you happen to know, whether those UWP API's are available to desktop applications?

Comment: It seems like all of them are COM-based. Is there any non-COM approach?

Comment: No, the shell is based on COM. At the filesystem level you will only see placeholder and/or sparse files but there is no information about the sync state there.

Comment: @Anders Not entirely true, see my answer.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Nice but MSDN has not caught up yet if these are actually going to get documented.